# Expo Path Aliases not recognize when bundle

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using path alias for my expo project, however, when I tried to bundle, it throw error that "@screens" not found in project, which mean that metro didn't recognize the path alias that I'm using

I have set

```
extraNodeModules: {
'@screens': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/screens'),
}
```

in metro.config.js as many sources, but it's still not working.